# split multiple delimiters using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract only the FREE HEAP count value which is 1400 from the below line. Here i'm using split function twice to get the value. Can somone help me to get a single regex that would extract the value 1400 using split function here.

```
my @split_val = split(',',$line);
print $split_val[2];
my @split_val1= split(':',$split_val[2]);
```

Input string:

```
2014-04-23 14:66:87,666 INFO  - HEAP - [USAGE: 1948.3, FREE: 1400, MAX: 3597.5]; NON-HEAP - [USAGE: 611.9, FREE: 52.2, MAX: 1776.0]; CLASSES - [Loaded: 67007, Unloaded: 3237, Left: 63770]; THREADS - [Count: 342]
```

output:

```
1400
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use split? match is more convenient here:

```
my $str = '2014-04-23 14:66:87,666 INFO  - HEAP - [USAGE: 1948.3, FREE: 1400, MAX: 3597.5]; NON-HEAP - [USAGE: 611.9, FREE: 52.2, MAX: 1776.0]; CLASSES - [Loaded: 67007, Unloaded: 3237, Left: 63770]; THREADS - [Count: 342]';
my ($freeValue) = $str =~ /(?<=FREE: )(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/;
print $freeValue,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
1400
```

Comment: but this regex would match both free count for heap and non heap

Comment: means 1400 and 52.2 correct ?

Comment: @user3834663: Sorry, I don't get you.Do you want to get only `1400` or all values that are after `FREE:`?

Comment: I need to get only the HEAP FREE count value which is 1400 not NON HEAP FREE value which is 52.2

Comment: Also i need to match if the free count has decimal values example 1400.1

Comment: @user3834663: See my edit.

Comment: sorry but that still match 1400 and 52.2

Comment: @user3834663: No, it doesn't. How do you use the code above? Please, edit your question and add more context. The sample script I gave outputs only `1400`